When zooming out of SVG the colors fade
I've been writing some math-visualisations using plain Javascript,HTML,CSS. I am working on the Fibonacci binary word fractal (see working example). In order to be able to see the ever growing image, I calculate the boundaries of the lines drawn and then adjust the image.
The image is drawn using a <Polyline> in an SVG-element using black stroke and stroke-width of 1 pixel. Up till iteration 15 the image fits pretty normal on the SVG-element of 1500x900 pixels. See the image below

When increasing the iterations the lines do not fit and the script will set a viewBox so that the image will fit. This means that the image is zoomed out. However, also the colors are fading. See the image below:

Anyone got a solution or is this a property of zooming out in an SVG?
The other solution is to recalculate the whole image using shorter line lengths, but this will require some serious refactoring...

That's just antialiasing. Your browser simply can't draw a line that's 1/2 a pixel wide so it draws a faded 1 pixel line.

You could also let the line width depend on the iteration level. Higher iterations get thicker lines. This will however mean that you loose detail, and if you're not very careful the whole image might just become black.

Please try adding vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke". The resulting visual effect of this value is that the stroke width is not dependent on the transformations of the element and zoom level. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/vector-effect

Good tips! Will try them now and report back

Based on the good tips from the comments I tried the following:
Using the css "vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;" helped a lot. This has the added benefit that the first iterations don't have a ridiculous thick line! Great!
svg polyline {
  stroke:black;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-linecap: square;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;
}


This yields the following result with 20 iterations:

Trying to let the line stroke-width depend on the iteration yields a slightly different result;:

The lines are course, but that could be fixed by tinkering with the relation between iteration and line width.
